# Spring data jpa not selecting all records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I'm beginner at Hibernate and I wan't to figure out some mechanisms.
I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish")
public class Dish implements Serializable {

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Category category;
}
```

And repository with such method:

```
@Query("select d from Dish d join fetch d.ingredients")
    Set<Dish> getDishesWithIngredientsAndCategory();
```

And I noticed, that I'm retrieving by this method **only** Dishes, that have associated ingredients. I have no idea how to get **all** Dishes, even that haven't ingredients?
And **second question** is: is it possible to combine in one @Query fetch two columns? Something like:

```
@Query("select d from Dish d join fetch d.ingredients, d.category")
```

I tried to use such query, but I'm receiving **QuerySelectionException**: "d.category is not mapped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That I'm retrieving by this method only Dishes, that have associated
>   ingredients.

Use `Left Join` instead of join: `@Query("select d from Dish d left join fetch d.ingredients")`

> And second question is: is it possible to combine in one @Query fetch
>   two columns?
>   You can try this:

`@Query("select d from Dish d join fetch d.ingredients join fetch d.category")`